# Yoxview mixing image with my site menubar

Tags: image, menubar, mixing, yoxview

Hye! i'm working on a drupal site, in which i used yoxview library to show images in popup. But i have a problem. The yoxview is mixing my websites menu bar with popup image. Anyone know how can i fix this problem? Please help!

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2edyu8l.png

See this image, This is what im trying to say.

Comment: Okay i got my answer myself. By playing with CSS a bit.
Actually all you have to do is to goto your drupal theme directory and open the style.css file. And this id as it in the end of that file and save it.

    
    #yoxview_popupWrap {
    z-index: 500;
    }